# Mixing signal with noise in frequency space (STFT)

Tags: audio, stft, speech-recognition, snr

I am working on a preprocessing function which is supposed to mix two audio signals `clean` and `noise` in the context of neural speech recognition.

For this I would like to augment the `clean` sample and mix it later with the `noise` sample.

Now, for efficiency reasons I would like to mix those to samples in frequency-space, as opposed to mixing them in time-space.

I wrote some Python code a while ago which mixes to signals randomly based on a given distribution and makes sure, that the noise sample does not get "too loud" relative to the clean signal:

```
# Calculate power of signals
s_pow = np.sum(np.abs(signal_waveform) ** 2.0) / len(signal_waveform)
n_pow = np.sum(np.abs(noise_waveform) ** 2.0) / len(noise_waveform)

# Draw SNR-value from given distribution
snr = eval('self.rnd.%s' % self.distribution)

# Calculate the scaling factor from SNR = 10 * log(P_s / P_n)
k = (s_pow / n_pow) * 10 ** (-snr / 10)
new_noise_waveform = np.sqrt(k) * noise_waveform

# Apply noise
final_signal_waveform = signal_waveform + new_noise_waveform

s = np.iinfo(signal_waveform.dtype).max / np.max(final_signal_waveform)
# Scale signal down as a whole if necessary to avoid clipping
if s < 1.0: 
  final_signal_waveform = final_signal_waveform * s
```

However, I was wondering how this could be achieved in frequency space. Here, I would like to augment the `clean` sample first in frequency-space and then mix it with the stft of the noise sample:

```
clean_stft = spectrum.stft(clean)
noise_stft = spectrum.stft(noise)

augmented_stft = spectrum.augment(clean_stft)  # e.g. time_stretch()

# How can this be done?
mixed = spectrum.mix(augmented_stft, noise_stft)

mel = spectrum.mel_features(mixed)
```

The reason is efficiency here. I don't want to convert everything back into time-space only having to run stft calculations again moments later.

So: How can I mix two stft spectrograms s.t. I can also control the relative loudness?

Comment: Why do you want to mix in frequency domain? That doesn't seem easier at all, seeing that the Fourier Transform is a linear operation to begin with.

Comment: @MarcusMüller For `time_stretch()` I'd do the following: `istft(phase_vocoder(stft(signal)))`. However, since I already calculate the STFT on my signal for the mel-features, the idea was to just augment the spectrum and mix it with the noise, without going back to the time-domain.